# Python Hexbin marginals offset from image produced

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, offset

I have a hopefully simple question.  When using the python hexbin plot option on some spatial data (Ra, and Dec are x and y) I also want to see the marginals on the side.  Happily there is a simple option 'marginals = True'....

Unhappily, as you can see below... the x-axis marginals are visibly offset from the hexagon produced image. I have tried adjusting parameters but the marginals on the x-axis always appear offset to the image (and there never seems to be a problem in y), any ideas would be appreciated. Please see the code and image below, Thanks in advance!

```
fig5=plt.figure(5)

ax=fig5.add_subplot(111)

imageh=plt.hexbin(Radeg[CoreL],
                  Decdeg[CoreL],
                  extent=[np.min(Radeg[CoreL]), np.max(Radeg[CoreL]), np.min(Decdeg[CoreL]), np.max(Decdeg[CoreL])],
                  alpha=0.7,
                  gridsize=20,
                  marginals=True,
                  vmin=5,
                  vmax=105,
                  cmap=get_cmap("jet"),
                  mincnt=5)

ax.axis([305,275,-40,-25])

cbar=plt.colorbar(imageh,extend='max')

cbar.set_label(r'$\mathrm{Counts}$',fontsize=18)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{RA}$',fontsize=20)

ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{DEC}$',fontsize=18)

plt.show()
```

[image: The counts image produced by hexbin]

-- per request that I add data to test with..... my data is rather lengthy and unwieldily, but here is a standalone version that illustrates the problem. This is a altered version from 'Hooked' who posted in regard to a different hexbin question.

```
def generate_data(n):
    """Make random, correlated x & y arrays"""
    points = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=(0,0),
        cov=[[0.4,9],[9,10]],size=int(n))
    return points

if __name__ =='__main__':

    color_map = plt.cm.Spectral_r
    n = 1e4
    points = generate_data(n)

    xbnds = np.array([-20.0,20.0])
    ybnds = np.array([-20.0,20.0])
    extent = [xbnds[0],xbnds[1],ybnds[0],ybnds[1]]

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,9))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x, y = points.T
    image = plt.hexbin(x,y,cmap=color_map,gridsize=20,marginals=True,extent=extent,mincnt=1,bins='log')
    ax.set_xlim(xbnds)
    ax.set_ylim(ybnds)
    plt.grid(True)
    cb = plt.colorbar(image,spacing='uniform',extend='max')
    plt.show()
```

This code gives a similar image, but this time the marginals are offset in the x and y direction, the integral should be just in one direction, over the other variable, i.e. rows and columns. In theory I would expect a marginal on the side for every row and column I have data in.

[image: marginals from new code image]

Comment: Can you put up data we can test with?

Comment: See above for a data version, my suspicion is that somehow the marginals are setting different bins or bin centers than the hexograms themselves but I have not been able to confirm this as yet.

Comment: I have the exact same thing happening,  with pretty much the same genre of code as posted above.  I also wanted to have custom scales (min and max) so the hexbin had custom "padding" between the area where the data is bound and the scales.  However,  there appears to be no way to control the scales of the marginals.  Looks like the fix may take digging into the source code.